# Java Error: NumberFormatException

Tags: java, numberformatexception

My Goal: The camera is trying to get the location of the terrain and follow it live so I can see where its being placed so once I click the button it will add the terrain in that location. The reason for the camera is to find where I'm placing the terrain so I don't place it in the wrong spot but I need to update the camera position then with where the terrain location is when I type something.

My Problem: Ok so the issue is that I have a editor gui to change the resiveTex so when I do I can see the camera move with the place of the terrain I'm adding "live". But it seems to break if I enter a new value plsss help me by telling me whats going on I tried looking it up but its a bit confusing!

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at entities.Camera.TerLocToFloat(Camera.java:39)
at entities.Camera.move(Camera.java:47)
at Run.MainLoop.main(MainLoop.java:146)
```

Window.java

```
public class Window {

    public static boolean NewTerrainCamPos = false;

    public static String textVal;
    public static String textVal2;
    public static String resiveTex = "1";
    public static String resiveTex2;

    public static final int Width = 1000;
    public static final int Height = 720;
    public static final int FPS_CAP = 120;

    private static long lastFrameTime;
    private static float delta;

    public static void createDisplay(){

        ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);

        try {
             Canvas openglSurface = new Canvas();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                //.............................
                JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu terrain  = new JMenu("Terrain");
                menuBar.add(terrain);
                menuBar.add(terrain);
                JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
                JMenuItem newTerrain = new JMenuItem("add Terrain");
                JMenuItem editTerrain = new JMenuItem("Edit Terrain");

                newTerrain.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        NewTerrainCamPos = true;
                        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
                        frame2.setVisible(true);
                        frame2.setSize(300, 300);
                        //...............................
                        GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(3,2);
                        frame2.setLayout(experimentLayout);
                        //.....................................
                        JLabel xCord = new JLabel("XCoords: ");
                        JLabel zCord = new JLabel("ZCoords: ");
                        JTextField text = new JTextField();
                        JTextField text2 = new JTextField();

                        text.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

                            @Override
                            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
                                resiveTex = text.getText();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                            }

                        });

                        resiveTex2 = text2.getText();

                        JButton createTerrain = new JButton("CreateTerrain");

                        createTerrain.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                            TIDF terrainFileID;
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){
                                NewTerrainCamPos = false;
                                textVal = text.getText();
                                textVal2 = text2.getText();
                                TIDF.terrainIDFile();
                            }
                        });

                        frame2.add(xCord);
                        frame2.add(text);
                        frame2.add(zCord);
                        frame2.add(text2);
                        frame2.add(createTerrain);
                    }
                });

                editTerrain.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        JFrame frame3 = new JFrame();
                        frame3.setVisible(true);
                        frame3.setSize(300, 300);
                        //......................................
                        GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(3,2);
                        frame3.setLayout(experimentLayout);
                        //......................................
                        JButton select = new JButton("Select");
                        String  terrainLocList[] =
                            {
                                "Item 1",
                                "Item 2",
                                "Item 3",
                                "Item 4"
                            };

                        JList list = new JList(terrainLocList);
                        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                        list.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
                        frame3.add(list);
                        frame3.add(select);
                    }
                });

                terrain.add(newTerrain);
                terrain.add(editTerrain);
                terrain.add(exit);
                frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
                //.........................................

                frame.setSize(1100, 1000);
                frame.add(openglSurface);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                openglSurface.setSize(1000, 720);
                Display.setParent(openglSurface);

            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(Width, Height));
            Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
            frame.setTitle("Game editor 0.1");
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
        lastFrameTime = getCurrentTime();
    }

    public static boolean Returnboolean(){
        return NewTerrainCamPos;
    }

    public static String getTex1() {
        return textVal;
    }

    public static String getTex2(){
        return textVal2;
    }

    public static String getTexupdate(){
        return resiveTex;
    }

    public static String getTexupdate2(){
        return resiveTex2;
    }

    public static void updateDisplay(){
        Display.sync(FPS_CAP);
        Display.update();
        long currentFrameTime = getCurrentTime();
        delta = (currentFrameTime - lastFrameTime)/1000f;
        lastFrameTime = currentFrameTime;
    }

    public static float getFrameTimeSeconds(){
        return delta;
    }

    public static void closeDisplay(){
        Display.destroy();
    }

    private static long getCurrentTime(){
        return Sys.getTime()*1000/Sys.getTimerResolution();
    }

}

public class Camera {

     private static final float TERRAIN_HEIGHT = 0;
     private boolean FPS = false;
     private boolean isInAir = false;

     private float distanceFromPlayer = 40;
     private float angleAroundPlayer = 0;

     private Vector3f position = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
     private float pitch = 20;
     private float yaw;
     private float roll;

     private static final float RUN_SPEED = 20;
     private static final float GRAVITY = -50;
     private static final float JUMP_POWER = 30;
     private float upwardsSpeed = 0;

     private Player player;

     public Camera(Player player){
         this.player = player;
     }

     public void TerLocToFloat(){
         String numberAsString = Window.getTexupdate();
         int number = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);  
         position.x = number;
         position.z = 0;
     }

     public void move(){
         if(Window.Returnboolean() == true){
             AddTerrainCamPos();
             TerLocToFloat();
         } else{
             viewState();
         } 
     }    
}
```

Comment: If asking about an exception or error, always post the full exception or error message and indicate which line(s) are involved. Please help us help you.

Comment: sure ill add it, forgot to by accident thanks for letting me know

Comment: Lot of problems with that code that I can see off the bat including using a KeyListener on a JTextField, something you should never be doing. Please explain more about what exactly this code is trying to do, so we can give decent help in depth.

Comment: You're also grossly over-using the static modifier making your code very hard to update and especially to mock/test/debug. All that code in Window, except for any constants, should not be static, and this suggests that you should consider a re-write. Also you have many important GUI objects buried in method scope and thus unaccessable. Most importantly the code snippets you've posted cannot compile and run for us, and so we cannot test your code directly. Please consider creating and posting a valid [mcve] (please read the link).

Comment: A guess -- Camera is trying to get the text before the user or the program has had a chance to place data into the JTextField. Time to do some debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 39 in Camera.java

```
String numberAsString = Window.getTexupdate();
int number = Integer.parseInt(numberAsString);
```

Where `numberAsString`  is empty string that causing the NFE

Try using the following method to parse the integer by setting defaultValue to 0

```
public static int parseInteger( String string, int defaultValue ) {
  try {
    return Integer.parseInt(string);
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e ) {
    return defaultValue;
  }
}
```